# WCF Serialization exception on OperationContract with params object[] which contains an array

Tags: c#, arrays, wcf, serialization

For the example:
My Service contract

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IProvider
{
    [OperationContract]
    DataSet CreateDataSetFromSQL(string command, params object[] par);
}
```

Evrything works fine until one of the params is an Array/List/ArrayList.
I get a serialization exception:

```
data contract name 'ArrayOfanyType:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.
```

As I mentiond I get the same error for string array when its one of the parameters.

Client

```
    private static ChannelFactory<IProvider> _channel;
    private static IProvider _proxy;
    private static DataTransferClient _client;

    public DataSet CreateDataSetFromSQL(string commandCode, params object[] par)
    { 
       return _proxy.CreateDataSetFromSQL(commandCode, par);
    }
```

Any idea how to workaround it ?

Comment: while generating client? what is the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case you did not actually read the error message:

Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the [KnownTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

As your type is "object", anything that is not "just an object" is not known statically and needs to be added via KnownType-Attribute. If you want to pass a `List<Whatever>`, you need to put the `KnownType` attribute with the type of `List<Whatever>` on top of your service.

As you did not post your service but only your *interface*, you can also use the [ServiceKnownType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute on your interface instead:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(List<string>))] // <== this will enable the serializer to send and receive List<string> objects
public interface IProvider
{
    [OperationContract]
    DataSet CreateDataSetFromSQL(string command, params object[] par);
}
```